# Unbiased variance estimate (n-1) simulation in python fails

Tags: python, statistics

I was trying to write a little program that simulates sampling from random numbers in Python3. But it seems to show the opposite of what I intended. What am I doing wrong? It must be extremely easy, but I don't get it.

```
import random
import statistics
import math

pcounter = 0
counter = 0
for loop in range(1000):
    l = []
    for x in range(500):
        l.append(random.randint(1,1000))

    m = statistics.mean(l)
    v = list(l)
    v[:] = [(x-m)**2 for x in v]
    realvariance = sum(v)/len(v)
    #print("Real Variance: " + str( sum(v)/len(v)))
    #print("Real Mean: " + str(m))


    sample = random.sample(l, 10)
    v = list(sample)
    #print(v)
    v[:] = [(x-m)**2 for x in v]
    samplem = statistics.mean(sample)
    samplebiasedvariance = sum(v)/len(v)
    samplevariance = sum(v)/(len(v)-1)

    print(samplebiasedvariance)
    print(samplevariance)
    print(realvariance)
    print((samplebiasedvariance - realvariance)**2 < (samplevariance - realvariance)**2)
    if (samplebiasedvariance - realvariance)**2 < (samplevariance - realvariance)**2:
        pcounter = pcounter + 1     
        print("biased Variance wins: " + str(pcounter))

    else:
        counter = counter + 1
        print("Variance wins: " + str(counter))

print("biased Variance wins: " + str(pcounter))
print("Variance wins: " + str(counter))
```

This results in:

```
biased Variance wins: 563
Variance wins: 437
```

But it should be the other way around: I would expect the biased Variance to be worse then the unbiased Variance that is calculated using (n-1). Therefore it should be more often closer to the true population Variance (realvariance) then the biased one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the other way around"?

Comment: Well I would expect the biased Variance be worse then the unbiased Variance, that is calculated using (n-1). Therefore it should be more often closer to the true population Variance (realvariance).

Answer (score 1):

"Bias" is a misleading term -- it suggests some kind of moral problem in a mathematical formula.

What you are looking at is essentially the mean square error of the two variance estimators. (Whichever is closer to the actual value will have lesser mean square error.) It turns out the unbiased sample variance has greater mean square error than the usual biased sample variance, which in turn has greater mean square error than sample variance computed with 1/(n + 1) instead of 1/n or 1/(n - 1).

If I understand correctly, if you put the 1/(n + 1) estimator into your program, you should find that it is more often closer to the actual value than either of the other two.

This topic is discussed on the Wikipedia page for [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) under the heading "Population variance and sample variance". No doubt there are many other resources.

Comment: Thats exactly what I expected: n-1 better than n, n better than n+1. But I got n better n-1, n -1 better than n+1.

Comment: Well, the results say that mse(n + 1) < mse(n) < mse(n - 1) where mse = mean square error, i.e. the average value of  (calculated value minus exact value)^2. Try calculating mse for all three. Take a look at resources for "bias-variance tradeoff" if you are interested in this topic.